# ASP.NET GridView DataBinding before Event Handlers

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview, objectdatasource

I'm working with a grid which is bound to an `ObjectDataSource`. In this grid, there is one column with a `DropDownList` (`AutoPostBack` is `true`) and a `Rating`. Those controls are supposed to enable the user to alter the data with immediately.

Unlike `RowCommand` (edit: in a `ButtonField`), the controls' handlers (`SelectedIndexChanged` and `RatingChanged` respectively) fire *after* data binding. Thus, I'll either not have up-to-date data or have to bind again by calling `DataBind`. Neither of these is that cool. The controls do not support row commands.

What is the best thing to tackle this? Am I getting some the concepts wrong, or handling the wrong events?

Here I have some code:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void ObjectDataSource1_ObjectCreating(object sender, ObjectDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ObjectInstance = new MyDataSource();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        // before selecting with ButtonField
        // after selecting with TemplateField + Control Event
        Debug.WriteLine("Command Handler");
    }

    protected void Unnamed2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Button event handler, after selecting
        Debug.WriteLine("Button Click Handler");
    }

    protected void ObjectDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Selecting invoked by ASP.NET data binding
        Debug.WriteLine("Selecting");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do say bind again ? when is the first time ?

Comment: The first time is before the button handler fires, invoked by ASP.NET data binding magic (to be honest, I do not know the details well, I guess I'll dig in). Anyway: I added some code, and the `ObjectDataSource1_Selecting` method is hit before `Unnamed2_Click`, which is my button's event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the datasource and databind the grid explicitly in OnLoadComplete event of the page.

Comment: Thank you, but apparently `Unnamed2`'s `Click` event does not fire at all.